# Is the "Napkin conjecture" open? (origami)

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, origami-folding

The falsity of the following conjecture would be a nice counter-intuitive fact.

Given a square sheet of perimeter $P$, when folding it along origami moves, you end up with some polygonal flat figure with perimeter $P'$.
**Napkin conjecture**: You always have $P' \leq P$.

In other words, you cannot increase the perimeter using any finite sequence of origami folds.

**Question 1**: Intuition tells us it is true (how in hell can it increase?). Yet, I think I read somewhere that there was some weird folding (perhaps called "mountain urchin"?) which strictly increases the perimeter. Is this true?
*Note 1*: I am not even sure that the initial sheet's squareness is required.

I cannot find any reference on the internet. Maybe the name has changed; I heard about this 20 years ago.

The second question is about generalizing the conjecture.

**Question 2**: With the idea of generalizing the conjecture to continuous folds or bends (using some average shadow as a perimeter), I stumble on how you can mathematically define bending a sheet. Alternatively, how do you say "a sheet is untearable" in mathematical terms?
*Note 2*: It might also be a matter of physics about how much we idealize bending mathematically.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napkin_folding_problem Has some relevant information, you were probably thinking of the "sea urchin" solution, however, it does require some stretching of the paper.

Comment: There are several references to this problem in Lang, Robert J., Origami design secrets, Mathematical methods for an ancient art. A K Peters, Ltd., Natick, MA, 2003. ISBN: 1-56881-194-2, MR2013930 (2004g:52001).  Unfortunately, the relevant pages aren't available on Google. 

Comment: from the MO : if you google "napkin conjecture" you do not get the wikipedia entry.So I had done my homework..

Comment: "https://www.math.lsu.edu/~verrill/origami/perimeter/" also claims to give an example where the perimeter increases.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is a general version of this question which is known as *"the rumpled dollar problem"*.  It was posed by  V.I. Arnold at his seminar in 1956. It appears as the very first problem in [*"Arnold's Problems"*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=LqvLnu8c3ToC&printsec=frontcover&dq=arnold%2527s+problems&source=bl&ots=l0ULwBNvsc&sig=mLNHb1upSiddEtfrHRjbjvJPfzE&hl=en&ei=6ZPpTIvqLcuaOozXvZEK&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> Is it possible to increase the perimeter of 
>   a rectangle by a sequence of foldings and unfoldings?

According to the same source (p. 182),

> Alexei Tarasov has shown that a rectangle admits a realizable folding with arbitrarily large perimeter. A realizable folding means that it could be realized in such a way as if the rectangle were made of infinitely thin but absolutely nontensile paper. Thus, a folding is a map $f:B\to\mathbb R^2$ which is isometric on every polygon of some subdivision of the rectangle $B$. Moreover, the folding $f$ is realizable as a piecewise isometric homotopy which, in turn, can be approximated by some isotopy of space (which corresponds to the impossibility of self-intersection  of a paper sheet during the folding process).

Have a look at

- A. Tarasov, *Solution of Arnold’s “folded rouble” problem.* (in Russian) Chebyshevskii Sb. 5 (2004), 174–187.
- I. Yashenko, *[Make your dollar bigger now!!!](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF03025296)* Math. Intelligencer 20 (1998), no. 2, 38–40.

---

A history of the problem is also briefly discussed in Tabachnikov's [review](http://www.math.psu.edu/tabachni/prints/Arnoldpr.pdf) of  "Arnold's Problems":

> It is interesting that the problem was solved by origami practitioners way before it was posed (at least, in 1797, in the Japanese origami book “Senbazuru Orikata”).

Comment: A reference is A S Tarasov, Solution of Arnolʹd's "folded ruble'' problem. (Russian. Russian summary) Chebyshevskiĭ Sb. 5 (2004), no. 1(9), 174–187. MR2098977 (2005e:52005). 

Comment: @Jérôme JEAN-CHARLES: You are welcome.

Comment: @Andrey Rekalo : may be you knew it already but the general audience (as well as me) would appreciate it for the sake of poetry.

“Senbazuru Orikata” stands for  "Folding a thousand cranes" (Sen =1000 ,zuru = crane , orikata =folding). Why a thousand folds is not totally clear : something to do with the fact that the result was used for garlands (long ones I guess) in ceremonies.  

Comment: @Jérôme: Thank you for the nice comment!

Comment: The complete title is *hi den sen ba zuru ori kata* (秘傳千羽鶴折形).  The "Hiden" means secret, and the "ba" (literally "feather") is a marker that makes it clear that the thousand is counting birds.  There is an incomplete scan at: http://www.origami.gr.jp/SenbazuruOrikata/

Comment: @S. Carnahan: Thanks for the nice addition.

Comment: A video showing A S Tarasov solution can be found at the [source file](https://arxiv.org/e-print/1405.6606v3) of  Anton Petrunin and Allan Yashinski [lecture notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.6606) on piecewise distance preserving maps.

Answer (score 27):

Permit me to supplement Andrey's definitive answer.

First, as Gerry Myerson says, this problem is discussed in Robert Lang's
*[Origami Design Secrets](http://173-14-177-170-newengland.hfc.comcastbusiness.net/product.asp?ProdCode=1942)*: pp.315-318, under the title "The Margulis Napkin Problem."
He credits the problem to Gregori Margulis.

Second, the problem is discussed in Igok Pak's book
*[Lectures on Discrete and Polyhedral Geometry](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/book.htm)*, p.354, which is available online.
You can pretty much guess the proof from the following instructive figure of Igor's:

[image: Napkin]

Third, there is another surprising result that is intellectually analogous to
increasing the perimeter by folding: The volume enclosed by any convex polyhedron
can be increased by bending the surface (retaining intrinsic isometry) to render it nonconvex!
See Chapter 39 of Igor's book, p.339ff.

Comment: Thank you: a very very nice reference ,I downloaded the book, such beautiful drawings. Yet I must confess the above is not enough for me to see the folds ( though I looked in the book only at the part you mentioned). 
Is there (roughly) a  date for resolution, the book says "unsolved for decades" (but not from when)? 

Comment: @JJ-J: It depends on what you mean by "resolution."  Here is Robert Lang: "several origami artists had created models [that solved the problem] years before it had even arisen in mathematical circles." Among those artists is Lang himself, I gather.  So this may be a case where the solution was known before the problem was posed!

Comment: OK I get it and I think this is a very interesting epistemological fact. Definitely a hard riddle that of asking a mathematician :" Give me a problem whose solution was known much before it was answered?" 

Answer (score 26):

In addition to the answers above, here are some remarks from [my paper in Russian](http://arxiv.org/abs/1004.0545); part of it used in the [last lecture here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1405.6606).
(Sorry for self-advertisement.)

**1.** An other solution. 
It is based on idea of Yashenko [Math. Intelligencer 20 (1998)].
This way you can increase the perimeter just a bit,
but it is done by repeating one fold (which is very simple but not "simple" in the sense below).

[image]

**2.** It is still not known if you can increase the perimeter by a sequence of natural folds;
i.e., folds like this:
[image]

I just learned that this problem also appears in [Pak's book](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/book.htm), Problem 40.16b;
it is marked by [$*$] which means that the problem is open.

Comment: I was a bit surprised by fact 2, after some reflection OK.  
Moreover I suddenly realize that something is dreadfully missing from the question: the figure at start and at the end should be flat ( a closed polygonal line made of finitely many segments).
In you first lines of 3 drawings can you confirm that the first two are in volumes and the last one is flat?  

Comment: Sorry I don't read Russian but the drawings are still worth looking at thank you.

Comment: @Jérôme: in (1), figure at start is net of folds for middle picture. it is iteration number 5 of "simple" folds. The picture on the right is the limit after infinite number of iteration, but it is enough to make finite number of iterations to increase the perimeter.